# What is the meaning of the last sentence?

Tags: meaning

This is a piece of text from the novel "The Salem's Lot".
What is the author trying to say in the last line and what does " so's " mean??

The text is:

"You can have my riot gun if you want it. That gun, it was Nolly’s idea. Nolly
liked to go armed, he did. **Not even a bank in town so’s he could hope someone
would rob it."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of that is

> You can have my riot gun if you want it. Nolly liked having powerful weapons, and getting the riot gun was his idea. It was a weird idea of course for this quiet community: did he imagine that he was going to have to deal with a gang of bank robbers when we are too small to have a bank?

It is spoken in uneducated English, and half the substance is implied rather than expressed. It is quietly making fun of Nolly.

Comment: What does " so's" mean though?

Comment: I mentioned that it is uneducated, colloquial speech. In received English, “so’s” would be “so that.”

Comment: Technically "*so's*" would be short for "so as".  But the meaning is often "so that".